# How to clean up nil policy error which shows GET 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

In the following case, some of the banks will not have branches.
Here is the controller.js code portion:

```js
function loadBranch(bankId) {
  BankMetadataService.getBranch(bankId).then(function(resp) {
    $scope.branchId = resp.data.id;
    $scope.validbool = true;
  }, function() {
    // if a bank does not have a branch
    console.log("No existing branch for bank.");
    $scope.validbool = false;
  });
}
```

here is the controller.rb code portion which looks for branches:

```
def bank_branch
  branch = BankMetadataBranch.where(bank_id: params[:bank]).first
  authorize branch, :show?
  render json: branch
end
```

From UI when I select a bank that has no branch it shows the following error in inspect console:
`GET http://localhost:.....?bank=1 500 (Internal Server Error)` with the `console.log` message.

How can I clean up that `500(Internal Server Error)` message?

Answer (score 0):

If the matter is only the console, use `console.clear()`!

Comment: In my understanding it's not related to console.log

Comment: It clears the console though. before your `console.log("No existing branch for bank.");` put this `console.clear()`.